# Multi select filter on comma separated object

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, filter

Using angularjs I wish to have a number of checkboxes that when checked they apply a filter to the data based on any number of the 'tags' selected. The property `tag` contains comma separated values. Each value will be attributed to a checkbox.

Checkboxes: `Shoulder, Knee, Hand, Foot, Core Stability, Back`

Data:     `{
"id": "2",
"name": "Neutral Spine on Gym Ball - Single Leg and Arm Lift ",
"perform_set": "3",
"perform_rep": "20",
"perform_rest": "30 sec",
"tags": ["Shoulder","Core Stability","Back"]
},`

I have about 4000 records that are structured like this. I am open to arranging the tags differently, these have not been added to the data. Ideally I need to get this correct from the start as it is going to be quite time consuming entering them for each exercise.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `"tags": "Shoulder","Core Stability","Back",` is syntax error...

Comment: Question regarding your filtering. Do you want the filters to function like "AND" or "OR"? If I chose the filters "Shoulder" and "Knee", should your result still appear as it satisfies one of the filter criteria or would it be hidden because it does not meet all filter criteria.

Comment: They are to be AND filters so if someone was searching for an exercise that was for both the Back and Shoulder then the result would show for both. Ideal is that the specific exercise shows like the shopping filter on Amazon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be what you want based on your comment to me in the question:

**(Ignore the snippet below as it is required for me to link to the plnkr)**

http://plnkr.co/edit/Xg7tGAQvBy3C6PjNROSH?p=preview

[image]

```
$scope.ApplyFilter = function() {
   $scope.FilteredData = $scope.Data;
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.ActiveFilters.length; i++) {
      $scope.FilteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.FilteredData, $scope.ActiveFilters[i], undefined);
   }
    };
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much!! 90% of the way there... I am getting some strange behavior as the filter is being applied when I click OFF the checkbox. Also can I limit results / shown results as performance is a little poor with 4000 items.

Comment: @Taylorsuk You'd have to limit the amount of records passed to the filter function, something like: $filter('filter')(Get500Records($scope.FilteredData),... A lot of times the limiting of results is done on the server side.

Comment: Can you shed any light on why it works when I deselect a checkbox rather than selecting one?

Comment: @Taylorsuk The plunk i linked should work when you select a box. You'll notice that the AddFilter call checks for selected before adding it to the filter array.

Comment: Indeed the plunk works perfectly but for some reason my implementation works on de-selection... I will carry on experimenting. Thanks very much for taking to time to give me the solution.

Comment: I have changed `ng-click` to `ng-change` and it now works perfectly... I see that this is documented here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Answer (score 0):

Below is some pseudo-code that represents just one of many different ways to do it.

```
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model='filters.neck'>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model='filters.leg'>

   <tr ng-repeat="data in yourdata | filter: filteredData(data)">

    $scope.filters = {"neck":false,"leg":false}
    $scope.currentFilters = [];
    $scope.$watch("filters",$scope.setFilters,true);

    $scope.setFilters = function() {
       // Something changed. Construct an arrow that containers the items to filter
       // e.g. $scope.currentFilters = ["neck"] because neck is checked
    };

    $scope.filtereddata = function (item) {
      var ret = false;
      if(item.currentFilters contains one of the items in item.tags ) {
         ret = true;
      } 
      return ret;
    };
```